# Текст выходит за пределы Div'a

Tags: css, html

Начал изучение языка разметки недавно, и столкнулся с проблемой.

```css
body,p,a {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.logo {
    width:500px;
    height:150px;
    background-color: #444;
    margin:0;
    display: block;
}
.logo-img {
    display: block;
    width:35%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Index</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/3eR6rb0.png" class="logo-img">
        <p class="logo-text">international</p>
    </div>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Хотелось бы чтобы текст находился в том же Div'e что и картинка,чтобы его можно было редактировать при помощи CSS.

`display:inline-block` не помогает.

Answer (score 1):

Тег `p` - блочный элемент, испол. тег `span`

Для изображения - добавить `max-height: XXpx`

Пример

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.logo {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
}

.logo-img,
.logo-text {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.logo-text {
  padding: 15px;
}

.logo-img {
  max-height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/3eR6rb0.png" class="logo-img">
  <span class="logo-text">international</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

добавьте `float:left` в `.logo-img`.
Чтобы было так:

```
 .logo-img {
    display: block;
    width:35%;
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.logo-img {
    display: block;
    width:35%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```